# How can I load more data on scrolling down with FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have data that was insert PostKey and Rating by cloud function. Following this picture [newfeed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U290e.png), [post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orCv3.png)

and I use FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter to get data

```
FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter<Post, FeedFragment.PostViewHolder> firebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter<Post, FeedFragment.PostViewHolder>(
            Post.class,
            R.layout.post_row,
            FeedFragment.PostViewHolder.class,
            FirebaseRef.mNewfeedRef.child(UID),
            FirebaseRef.mPostRef
    ) {
```

Solution that I was thinks is

1. First one is orderByValue() and load StartAt(0) to EndAt(5) when scrolled to bottom it called StartAt(0) to EndAt(10) and so on but each time will load old data that could wasted traffic.
2. Second one is create new reference suppose is "newfeed-post" that have only top 5 items ordered by rating that get from "newfeed" and when I scroll down to load more I request to cloud function to let cloud function insert more 5 items from "newfeed" to "newfeed-post" that lower rating (eg. position 6-10).

Please help and let me know how to do this. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pagination is not supported by [FirebaseUI-Android](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/) components.  They currently require you to provide a single query that yields all the results to display.  There is no way to progressively supply more queries as a list is scrolled. Also see the [discussion in this issue on the Github repo for FirebaseUI-Android](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/issues/9).

Comment: Thanks for answered, I found library https://github.com/marcorei/Infinite-Fire/ Can i use this instead of single query.

Comment: I've just seen that for the first time, so I don't know if it works. But you can certainly give it a try.

Comment: Thanks @Doug Stevenson Maybe i should try to singleValueListener get data for insert to RecyclerView manually without FirebaseUI