# How to used Load More Functionality in RecycleView using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pagination, firebaseui

I am trying to fetch list of data. but Firebase databases more data available. so i try to load more of list of data using RecyclerView.

I have completed to Fetch List Details but not any idea, How to use Load More in Pagination with 1 to 10 and next 11 to 20?

My code is:

```
 public static class ShowDataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private final TextView image_title;
        private final ImageView image_url;
        private final TextView image_Desc;
        private final TextView time_upload;

        public ShowDataViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image_url = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fetch_image);
            image_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fetch_image_title);
            image_Desc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fetch_image_Desc);
            time_upload = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_upload);
            image_delete.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        private void Image_Title(String title,String desc,String time) {
            image_title.setText(title);
            image_Desc.setText(desc);
            time_upload.setText(time);
        }
        private void Image_URL(String imagename) {
            Glide.with(itemView.getContext())
                    .load(imagename)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
                    .error(R.drawable.imagenotavailable)
                    .into(image_url);
                }
    }


and 



    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ShowDataItems, ShowDataViewHolder>(ShowDataItems.class, R.layout.show_data_single_item, ShowDataViewHolder.class, myRef) {

                public void populateViewHolder(final ShowDataViewHolder viewHolder, final ShowDataItems model, final int position) {
                    viewHolder.Image_Title(model.getImage_Title(),model.getDescription(),model.getTime_upload());
                    viewHolder.Image_URL(model.getImage_URL());
                    loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            };
            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
            mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
            mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mFirebaseAdapter);
    }
```

How to solve this Issues? Please Give me any suggessions?

Comment: Pagination is currently not supported by the FirebaseUI components. See this answer from Doug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44508348/how-can-i-load-more-data-on-scrolling-down-with-firebaseindexrecycleradapter/44509947#44509947

Comment: Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen